# Unknown Os Character Set 'cp720' , switching to the default character set 'latin1'

Tags: java, mysql

When I run `mysql -root -p db2 <mySuperMarketDB.sql` and enter password then I get the following error:

> Unknown Os Character Set 'cp720' , switching to the default character set 'latin1'

How can I fix that?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 13):

Change encoding to 1252

```
c:\chcp 1252
```

You can change code page permanantly as follows:

1. Start -> Run -> regedit
2. Go to [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]
3. Add new String Value named: Autorun
4. Change the value to 'chcp 1252'

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to run some sql  text file in mysql and get an error like this:

C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\mysql.exe: Unknown OS character set 'cp862'.
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\mysql.exe: Switching to the default character set 'latin1'.

You get the error because the engine is use the default. To set the default to UTF-8 in "my.ini" file you have to add this lines:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8


[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

save the file and restart the service.

credits goes here : https://shlomovitz.blogspot.com/2013/11/unknown-os-character-set-cp862-and.html?fbclid=IwAR15ADTZd5E3cKeQX0w2vR6b5Ef8GBW86ptpd-M2CpyORp3bNkLN2QiXLek